# remove entity from entity form field if custom condition is matched

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I have an unsubscribe form, where the first field is a entity field, fetching my UnsubscribeType entities :

```
$builder
    ->add('type', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Evo\SubscriptionBundle\Entity\UnsubscribeType',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'Choose process type',
        'empty_value'   => 'Choose an option',
        'empty_data' => null,
        'label_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'control-label',
        ),
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
    ))
```

this collection contains 2 entities, #1 and #2. I would like to remove entity #2 from the select field if a custom test about the authed user fails.

Let's say I'd to test `$this->getUser()->getCustomField()`. If it is `false`, then i would like to remove entity #2 from the select field containing my UnsubscribeType entities.

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could pass to the form builder the result of the test from you controller and then, either use `'property' => 'name'` or `'choices => // fetch entity #1 here`.

So, something like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if($options['customField'] === TRUE)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'entity', array(
               'class' => 'Evo\SubscriptionBundle\Entity\UnsubscribeType',
               'property' => 'name',
               // ..
        ;
    }
    else
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'entity', array(
               'class' => 'Evo\SubscriptionBundle\Entity\UnsubscribeType',
               'choices' => $options['customField'],
               // ..
        ;
    }
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    // ..

    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'customField'
    ));
}
```

And in your controller:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new EntryType(), $entry, array(
        'customField' => $this->getUser()->getCustomField()
));
```

with `getCustomField()` returning either true or the entity (or collection of entities) that you want populating your select field. My solution would involve changing the getCustomField method though, don't know if that would suit.